# Can't understand the result of TensorOverflow train.QueueRunner

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, queue

Sorry, I'm a beginner of TensorFlow. The following is just a TensorFlow's code using two threads to enqueue and dequeue independently.

```
import tensorflow as tf

Q = tf.compat.v1.FIFOQueue(1000, tf.float32)
var = tf.Variable(0.0)
data = tf.compat.v1.assign_add(var, tf.constant(1.0))
en_q = Q.enqueue(data)
qr = tf.train.QueueRunner(Q, enqueue_ops=[en_q])
init_op = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = qr.create_threads(sess, coord=coord, start=True)
    for i in range(300):
        print(sess.run(Q.dequeue()))
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

The result is like following:

```
3.0
7.0
10.0
14.0
18.0
21.0
26.0
....
```

I'm quite confused about this result. Since `Q` is a FIFO queue, even though the dequeue and enqueue are in two different threads, the number enqueued still should be `1,2,3,4,5,6,...`. Why is it possible the dequeued number can be `3,7,10,14,....` Where are the numbers `1, 2, 4, 5, ...`?

Answer (score 0):

The randomness has nothing to do with the `FIFOqueue` but is an expected behavior with the concurrency of thread execution. There are definitely more than just 2 threads involved.

To simplify things, let's try to run your code without the `for` loop, add some `print` statements & a `sleep` interval & see what happens:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import time

Q_size = 1000 # Q size
t = 1 # t in sec

Q = tf.compat.v1.FIFOQueue(Q_size, tf.float32)
var = tf.Variable(0.0)
data = tf.compat.v1.assign_add(var, tf.constant(1.0))
en_q = Q.enqueue(data)

qr = tf.train.QueueRunner(Q, enqueue_ops=[en_q])

init_op = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()

    print('*** before qr.create_threads ***')
    print('Q.size()', sess.run(Q.size()))
    print('var', var.eval())

    threads = qr.create_threads(sess, coord=coord, start=True)

    print('*** after qr.create_threads ***')
    time.sleep(t) # sleep t sec in main to wait for all threads to finish running.
    print('Q.size()', sess.run(Q.size()))
    print('var', var.eval())

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Output:

```
*** before qr.create_threads ***
Q.size() 0
var 0.0

*** after qr.create_threads ***
Q.size() 1000
var 1001.0
```

Before calling `qr`, nothing happens. There's nothing in the `FIFOQueue` `Q` & `var` stills equals 0. This is expected.

After calling `qr.create_threads` & setting `start=True`, `qr` does the following:

1. Starts populating `Q` with your `enqueue_ops` which in this case, is `en_q`. It will try to pack as many `en_q` ops as possible which is decided by your `Q` size.
2. Creating threads for each `en_q` in `Q`.
3. Run the threads concurrently. (At this point, given the size of `Q`, it's clear that there can't be only just 2 threads involved as mentioned by the OP.)

The `sleep` is introduce to allow all these threads to finish execution before we display the output. We want to know what is the size of `Q` & value of `var` after all threads created by `qr` finish running.

So as expected, `Q` is populated with 1000 `en_q` ops & `var` is added 1001 times.

Now, if we remove the `sleep` interval, we get random output like the one shown below.

Random output without `sleep`:

```
*** before qr.create_threads ***
Q.size() 0
var 0.0

*** after qr.create_threads ***
Q.size() 32
var 35.0
```

What the random output above is saying is that when we display the output in the main thread, `qr` is still populating the `Q`, creating & running the threads concurrently in the background.

Now, lets put your `for` loop back in while introducing another `sleep` interval in the loop:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import time

Q_size = 1000 # Q size
N =10 # range of for loop
t = 1 # t in secs

Q = tf.compat.v1.FIFOQueue(Q_size, tf.float32)
var = tf.Variable(0.0)
data = tf.compat.v1.assign_add(var, tf.constant(1.0))
en_q = Q.enqueue(data)

qr = tf.train.QueueRunner(Q, enqueue_ops=[en_q])

init_op = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()

    print('*** before qr.create_threads ***')
    print('Q.size()', sess.run(Q.size()))
    print('var', var.eval())

    threads = qr.create_threads(sess, coord=coord, start=True)

    print('*** after qr.create_threads ***')
    time.sleep(t) # sleep t sec in main to wait for all threads to finish running.
    print('Q.size()', sess.run(Q.size()))
    print('var', var.eval())

    print('*** for loop ***')
    for i in range(N):
        sess.run(Q.dequeue())
        time.sleep(t) # sleep t sec in main to wait for all threads to finish running.
        print('var', var.eval())
        print('.size()', sess.run(Q.size()))

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Introducing `sleep` allows background threads to finish before we display the variables in the main thread.

You can see in the output below that `var` increases seqentially now while `Q` size remains at 1000. Each `sess.run(Q.dequeue())` call now executes one `en_q` op from `Q`, adding 1 to `var`.

I hope this clears up that the randomness that you observed has nothing to do with `Q` being `FIFOqueue` or not. The randomness is caused by the expected behavior of thread parallelism.

Output:

```
*** before qr.create_threads ***
Q.size() 0
var 0.0

*** after qr.create_threads ***
Q.size() 1000
var 1001.0

*** for loop ***
var 1002.0
.size() 1000
var 1003.0
.size() 1000
var 1004.0
.size() 1000
var 1005.0
.size() 1000
var 1006.0
.size() 1000
var 1007.0
.size() 1000
var 1008.0
.size() 1000
var 1009.0
.size() 1000
var 1010.0
.size() 1000
var 1011.0
.size() 1000
```